# Networkx: how add randomly edges to network

Tags: python, networkx

I have two subgraph
[image: graph]`

```
p = (2 * 2364) / (128 ** 2)
U = nx.erdos_renyi_graph(128, p)
H = nx.erdos_renyi_graph(128, p)
G = nx.disjoint_union(U, H)`
```

How add 10 nodes between this subgraph?

Comment: When you say 10 nodes, you mean 10 random edges between U and H, right?

Answer (score 2):

If you ask for

```
G.nodes()
```

this will give you nodes numbered through 1..255

First 128 came from U and second 128 came from H [[source]](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.9.1/_modules/networkx/algorithms/operators/binary.html#disjoint_union), you can pick 2 nodes at random and create an edge. Knowing this you can add 10 random edges:

```
import random
for i in range(10):
    u = random.choice(range(128))
    v = random.choice(range(128, 256))
    H.add_edge(u, v)
```